# appending records using bcp into a csv or text file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, append, sql-server-express, bcp

how do I append records to an existing csv file on my C: drive by using BCP export of SQL Server.

**Name**

---

a

b

Now, this "Name" table has been updated with some new names:

**Name**

---

a

b

c

d

e

Now, i want to only export c ,d ,e to my existing csv file which already has a, b and c into it. i want to add these newly added records  in sql table to my csv file